# Navigating through powerpoint slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Writing a macro that copy/pastes a bunch of slides from one powerpoint to another. After this, I'm always left looking at the final slide, but I want the active/visible slide to be the first slide. Feels like this should be easy but I can't find anything that works. It's not in slideshow view, so SlideShowWindows won't help, and there's no "Activate" or anything like that. I tried

```
Slides(1).Select
```

but that still shows the last slide. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: [Edit]ing your question with more of your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub GotoSlide1()
    ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error message saying .View is an "invalid qualifier"

Comment: I test all code before posting, so I know it works. As Ben has already requested, please edit your original post adding your macro code so we can see how you are using the statement in context.